# Method controller does not exist.

Tags: php, datatable, controller, laravel-5

So I have used this format again. In my routes.php I have

```
Route::controller('datatables', 'HomeController', [
    'PaymentsData'  => 'payments.data',
    'getIndex' => 'datatables',
]);
```

In my HomeController.php I have

```
  public function getIndex()
    {
        return view('payments.index');
    }

    /**
     * Process datatables ajax request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function Payments()
    {
        return Datatables::of(DB::table('customer'))->make(true);
    }
```

Anytime I try `php artisan` I get `[BadMethodCallException] Method controller does not exist.`

Question, is this form of doing it Deprecation or why anyone spot something wrong?  Kindly assist. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The `controller` method is deprecated since Laravel 5.3. But now, you can use the `resource` method, which is meant for the same purpose as the `controller` method:

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers):

> Laravel resource routing assigns the typical "CRUD" routes to a controller with a single line of code. For example, you may wish to create a controller that handles all HTTP requests for "photos" stored by your application.

Use it as:

```
Route::resource('datatables', 'HomeController');
```

The downside of this *implicit* routing is that you have to name your methods consistently, more about it in the docs.

In most cases, better practise would be *explicit* routing, as it makes your code much more clear and understandable.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware that's never been available for Laravel 5. I haven't used 4 so I'm not sure about prior to 5. But in 5 you need to use `Route::get` and `Route::post`.

```
Route::get('datatables', ['as' => 'HomeController', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex']);
Route::get('payments-data', ['as' => 'HomeControllerPaymentsData', 'uses' => 'HomeController@Payments']);
```

Yep, it was removed as using implicit controllers is bad practice - https://github.com/illuminate/routing/commit/772fadce3cc51480f25b8f73065a4310ea27b66e#diff-b10a2c4107e225ce309e12087ff52788L259