# Route::controllers in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, apache2, laravel-5.3, php-7

> [BadMethodCallException]
>
> Method controllers does not exist.

```
Route::controllers(['auth' => 'Auth\AuthController', 'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',]);
```

How is in Laravel 5.3?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you asking? i think you just need to make `php artisan make:auth`, this will set up those route you're writing here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method controller does not exist.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449882/method-controller-does-not-exist)

Comment: No, I tried with php `artisan make:auth` but nothing changed, same error

Comment: @aynber the error is different because I have controllers and the fix in that answer still not work

Comment: Please elaborate your question a bit more.

Comment: Please elaborate your question a bit more.

Comment: Elaborate on your question please, If this is really your question maybe try checking the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing

Answer (score 1):

The Route::controller() has been deprecated (notes can be seen in the upgrade from 5.2 -> 5.3 on [the docs site](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade))

> Implicit controller routes using Route::controller have been deprecated. Please use explicit route registration in your routes file. This will likely be extracted into a package.

Instead you must explicitly list each route in not resourceful controllers like so:

```
Route::get('foo', 'FooController@foo');
```

If your question is aimed specifically at the auth routes only then as the comments on your question running `php artisan make:auth` or adding `Auth::routes();` to your routes\web.php file should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

May few dependency cannot injected in your project when you install via composer. You can try again to install a new copy or write the following lines in your project directory using the terminal.

```
composer install
```

or you can write

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Hope you can fix the problem.